# Retrieving results based on timeslots using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a function of mine that will return queries based on timeslots.

Here what I am trying to accomplish:

Using a start time `y-m-d`; I grab results that match that time slot.  Than I am given a `start hour` and an `end hour` `(00:00:00)` which I want to than compare the earlier results with to only grab the queries whos start hour and end hour are within or on the given `start hour` and `end hour`.

My question is can I do this all with one query in `PHP PDO (MySQL)` ?

`start time  format in database:` `Y-m-d`

`start and end hour format in database:` `00:00:00`

Suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: For a quich short answer, 'Yes you can do it with one query'. Now to be more specific I need to know, are both the date and time saved in the same field, i.e. Y-m-d h:m:s format or each in a separate field ?!

Comment: @AymanB. there are all in different fields.  One for `y-m-d` and one for `start hour` and `end hour`

Comment: Names: `start_time` - `start_time_hour` - `end_time_hour`

Comment: Would it sound right like this `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE start_time = '{START TIME}' AND start_time_hour >= '{Start Hour}' AND end_time_hour <= '{END Hour}';`

Comment: @AymanB. Yes that would sound right, a little more specific is it possible to than grab the results based on each hour until you get to the end hour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63612/discussion-between-ayman-b-and-david-biga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion we went through you would need a query like the following:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
       `tbl_name` 
    WHERE 
       `start_time` = '{Y-m-d}' AND 
       `start_time_hour` >= '{Start H}' AND 
       `end_time_hour` <= '{END H}' 
   ORDER BY 
       `start_time_hour`;
```